# C# CoreFTP - SFTP Connection Failing - connection timeout

Tags: c#, ftp, .net-core, sftp

I'm using this library with C# to connect and upload files to a server:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/CoreFtp/

I'm able to connect to FTP sites, but attempts made with SFTP respond with a connection timeout.

Anyone have an example of what to do when establishing a connection with SFTP?

Here's an example of what I'm doing:

```
using (var ftpClient = new FtpClient(new FtpClientConfiguration
                {
                    Host = FTPUrl,
                    Username = FTPUser,
                    Password = FTPPassword,
                    Port = FTPPort, // using port 21 for ftp, and port 22 for sftp
                    EncryptionType = FtpEncryption.Implicit,
                    IgnoreCertificateErrors = true
                }))
                {
                    await ftpClient.LoginAsync();

                    // do something with ftp client
                }
```

Comment: CoreFtp is an FTP client. It has nothing to do with SFTP, which is a completely different protocol.

Comment: Just figured there might be something in the library to handle both; but guess not. Thanks!